# RxJs: Collecting a set number of 'callbacks' from children

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a set number of children components that each have an asynchronous init. When all children are completed they should emit an event to the parent component signifying they are complete.

How do i collect all the children events and signify that they are all complete?

Comment: Do you need a Promise.all behavior? Or a different behavior where you only need one value emitted from each call? (once the last call is back. returning the values)

Comment: i think you need some kind of counter at parent component which will recieve "finished" event from every child and increment the counter. when counter will reach the number equal to children count - you will know they all done

Comment: Some example code might be helpful here to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi You could do something like this in your component: (dummy code):

```
      onInit(){

          let allPromiseObj: any = [];
          for (const childs of allChildrens) {          
            allPromiseObj.push(this.asyncProcess(childs));
          }

          //Checking if all resource json are loaded.
          Promise.all(allPromiseObj).then(() => {
           //fire events that all events are compmlete
          });

     }
    asyncProcess(child_data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         //do something aysnc here 
          resolve();
        });
      }
```

P.s: This code is not production ready.